# How to edit css style using javascript with complete css code for any component

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a CSS editor section for my page, I have to add an advanced CSS editor.
This editor should apply changes to the site's css using CSS code through a textarea, for example

```
#para1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

how can I edit this css style for "para1"?

**NOTE:** PARA1 is only an example, actually what I want is that it can identify any ID that I put in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you use a **class**:

```
$(".para1, .para2").css({"text-align": "left", "color": "blue"});
```

Try this if you use an **id**:

```
$("#para1, #para2").css({"text-align": "left", "color": "blue"});
```

Comment: I have updated my question, what I am looking for is that the javascript identifies the syntax, that is, it is not only for1, it is any id entered, it must capture it to be able to assign a value to the style

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use more than one class or id.

Comment: the problem is that as it is a textarea the user can enter anything, not just para1, para2, etc, that's just an example

Comment: Yes, the user can enter any text in the textarea, but it'll always be text (not an image for example), right? Also, your id will stay the same no matter what the user will enter. I have a feeling that you're confusing your id (id='para1') with the text that the user will enter. Even if the user will enter "para1" into the div with an id='para1', the id will not change. So, my solution should work. It will look at the div with an id='para1' and change ANY text that the user will enter in this div.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vanilla JavaScript and I understood it correctly, this is what you need:

```js
var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
para1.style.color = "red";
para1.style.textAlign = "center";
```

```html
<p id="para1">Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: the problem is that as it is a textarea the user can enter anything, not just para1, that's just an example

Comment: what is para1? is it an id or any thing else,

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you want to happen. Are you trying to create a style editor where the user can type code?

Answer (score 0):

using javascript,

```
let comp = document.querySelector("#para1");
comp.classList.add("newStyles");
```

This will add newStyles class to comp variable.

Comment: the problem is that as it is a textarea the user can enter anything, not just para1, that's just an example